# Why does the Robot Devil has the worst luck ever?

Tags: futurama

In "The Devil's Hands Are Idle Playthings", the Robot Devil loses his arms, he never can lay his hands on Bender's soul for lots of reasons, such as redemption (Ghost in the Machines), sacrificing his first born (Beast with a Billion Backs), etc. My guess would be that the God Robot has a certain beef with him, thus always turning things against him, probably because his god-awful music bits. :D

So: is it explained at any point in the series why Robot Devil is so unlucky? Is there some force working against him? Was he slated as the fall guy for some out-of-story reason?

Answer (score 2):

This is one of the running meta-gags in Futurama.

In most depictions of the Devil, he is shown to be unbeatable simply by virtue of being the Devil. Somehow or the other things will turn in his favour so he gets what he wants. He will either orchestrate events or have hidden clauses in the "contract".

But in Futurama, he is constantly being beaten and very rarely do things turn out his way. Most of the time it's just plain bad luck, as you pointed out, for the sake of comedy.

Answer (score -2):

The robot devil is always unlucky because he has bad karma, everything he does he does with bad intentions.

Comment: Do you have anything to back this affirmation?